# Big Query vs Text Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I wonder if Big Query is going to replace/compete with Text Search API? It is kinda stupid question, but Text Search API is in beta for few months and has very strict API calls limit. Bug Big Query is already there and looks very promising. Any hints what to chose to search over constantly coming error logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google BigQuery and the App Engine Search API fulfill the needs of different types of applications.

BigQuery is excellent for aggregate queries (think: full table scans) over fixed schema data structures in very very large tables. The aim is speed and flexibility. BigQuery lacks the concept of indexes (by design). While it can be used for "needle in a haystack" type searches, it really shines over large, structured datasets with a fixed schema. In terms of document type searches, BigQuery records have a fixed maximum size, and so are not ideal for document search engines. So, I would use BigQuery for queries such as: In my 200Gb log files, what are the 10 most common referral domains, and how often did I see them?

The Search API provides sorted search results over various types of document data (text, HTML, geopoint etc). Search API is really great for queries such as finding particular occurrences of documents that contain a particular string. In general, the Search API is great for document retrieval based on a query input.